# ExtjS How destroy controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

I have situation look like this, I have controller which has view dialog, dialog is not defined as that controller view, only window object I have created.When I am closing and destroying DOM of the dialog, the first event is working fine, after this this process is working two times.Therefore I conclude that my controller is remaining and it is calling dialog equal to null.How I can destroy that controller.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **destroy** function

```
dialogName.destroy;
```